# Attribute Tracemode not supported in App Config when defining trace sources

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, trace

There are plenty of tutorials covering the trace mode in app.config.. one of them is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which should work with version 2-4.5 of the .Net framework.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

In my case the source attributes are marked as not valid / not available.

->  source name="System.Net" *tracemode*="includehex" *maxdatasize*="1024"

I need to define the tracemode attribute to disable Hex Output in my Network trace log files. I searched varoius resources but everyone just states "cannot be, just ignore the errors". But ignoring doesn`t help, the Attributes are just skipped, default values are used.

I cannot use tracing via code since I need the direct tracing of Net / Net.Sockets which can not be defined directly

I tried the settings on different project with two versions of Visual Studio (2005, 2012) and various Framework Settings (2,3,4) but nothing helps.

Why are the attributes marked as invalid?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but I realized that the attribute tracemode cannot be specified for all of the assemblies listed in the sources that we want to plug to.

Even if the VS code editor raises this attribute as not allowed, it works on System.Net assembly and therefore, on each of its children (what matters to me in my case).

Here an example of what results in a functional web.config :

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
</trace>
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Cache" tracemode="protocolonly" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Http" tracemode="protocolonly" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.HttpListener" tracemode="protocolonly" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Sockets" tracemode="protocolonly" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" switchValue ="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="log4net" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

Hope my 2 cents helped.

Comment: Unfortunetly your solution doesn`t work for me. I Use only children of "System.Net" but tracemode="protocolonly", setup everything like you did but still doen`t change anything (still hex output included).

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN article you posted, just set the tracemode to "protocolonly" and the hex should not be written.

Comment: Unfortunately the attributes are just ignored. It is marked as not valid and the default value is used, regardless if I use tracemode="includehex" or tracemode="protocolonly"